# How do I set the timer to show how much time is left for the day to end?

Tags: javascript, liquid

I would like to put this timer to show how many hours are left for the day to end in Brasilia time, Brazil, I am not able to form something with gethours

```
{% assign productTags = product.tags %}  
{% if productTags contains 'contador' %}
<script>
  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.getHours();

      if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 29.5,       
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
  };
```

Can I do this with this code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to determine today and tomorrow's calendar date using the much *loved* [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You can get today's date in milliseconds since epoch using:

```js
const now = new Date()


// Sun Dec 11 2022 13:21:03 GMT-XXXX (Your Time Zone)
```

You can then get that in milliseconds since Epoch

```js
const nowMsSinceEpoch = now.getTime()

// 1670793708603
```

This is the basis for the solution. If you can find today's date in milliseconds and tomorrow at 00:00, you can compare the two:

```js
let tomorrow = new Date()
tomorrow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1)
tomorow.setHours(0,0,0,0)

// Mon Dec 12 2022 00:00:00 GMT-XXXX (Your Time Zone)
```

At this stage, you're ready to get the difference between tomorrow and today:

```js
const differenceMs = tomorrow.getTime() - now.getTime()
```

By subtracting one timestamp in relation to epoch from another that lives in relation to epoch, you now have a difference, and something you can now calculate the hours, with some accuracy. This is now just a matter of arithmetic. You'll need to determine how many milliseconds lie within an hour, and you you will seek what way you wish to round the number.

Comment: (nit) This will not work if it crosses the daylight savings time beginning or end, so add some mode code for that if need be.  AFAIK, right now, Brazil does not do DST so maybe *you* (other folks, maybe not) can ignore this [now].